# Client Side Routing - Any URL path

Tags: javascript, routes, path.js

Is there a simple client side routing solution that will take any URL path value and pass it on to a variable? I would like it so https://URL/path  saves the path value as a variable and loads index.html while preserving the URL.

I have looked at a couple of solutions ([path.js](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs) & [crossroads.js](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/)) but I don't quite understand how they work for binding any URL path and loading the default index.html file. I am not using any frameworks and would like to know if this is achievable with vanilla javascript.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant, check URL object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL (works on chrome and ff only)

Comment: in simpler terms - how would I redirect any /path to index.html while preserving the path in the url bar?

Comment: Oh I see. then you need to manipulate browser history. history.pushstate may help you . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: One option is to use an iframe with size of full page.

Comment: I guess there is no way around having the server send a page at the original URL. If a user enters your site it first asks your server for the URL. Client side solution require that the server sends code to the client first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will use the pushState() method for when the app is already loaded and find another solution for URL redirects.